# Method not allowed in Laravel. Why in this case?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to know why I have a "Not Allowed" method in this case. I'm trying to set a value to NULL (I have an hasClone column) when I delete an entry that I duplicated.

My controller :

```
public function destroyChanges($id)
  {
    $activity = Activity::findOrFail($id);
    $activity->delete();

    return redirect()->to('/admin/activity/setCloneNull/' . $activity->parent_id);
  }

public function setCloneNull($id, Activity $activity)
{
  $activity = $activity->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
  $activity->hasClone = NULL;
  $activity->save();
  return redirect(url('/admin/activity/'));
}
```

Routes :

```
  Route::delete('activity/destroyChanges/{id}', ['as' => 'cancel.activity', 'uses' => 'ActivityCrudController@destroyChanges']);
  Route::post('activity/setCloneNull/{id}', ['as' => 'setCloneNull.activity', 'uses' => 'ActivityCrudController@setCloneNull']);
```

EDIT : I get the error when I try to run the 'setCloneNull' method. The error is 405 Method not allowed

How to make it work? thank you !

Comment: _Where_ do you get a “not allowed” method error? Can you give us the actual error message please.

Comment: What are you using to make the request to that route?

Comment: @MartinBean I get the error when I try to run the 'setCloneNull' method. The error is 405 Method not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `destroyChanges` action is using the http method `delete`. When you redirect from it you keep the http method which the other route does not accept (because it's a `post`).
That is: You get method not allowed because you are not allowed to make a `delete` request to `/admin/activity/setCloneNull/`

Comment: Okay, thank you, but then how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Either change the second route to a `delete` route or move the logic to the first action (which I would recommend).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand, but if I'm in a DELETE route, I do not know how to modify a field (here, hasClone that I want to change to NULL). That's why I tried to get around by creating a POST route to modify the original entry.

Comment: You can do the same thing in a post as a delete. Only difference is the http method and what the client see/expect.

Comment: its because the redirect causes a GET.

Comment: Oh, a redirect changes method to `GET`? thought it kept the method through the redirect, but you might be right! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `$activity->delete()` method, thus deleting the `$activity` model and all its properties; Since you're trying to get the `$activity->parent_id` property of something that doesn't exist any more, you're getting the error.

**Update**: see @Jite's answer for proper reason, but please consider changing your code logic

Comment: I understand but I can get the parent_id in my redirect(). He gives me the URL with the correct ID.

Comment: Have a look at @Jite's answer. But please reconsider your logic, first do whatever and only at the end delete.

Answer (score 0):

Just `return redirect(url('/admin/activity/'));` after `$activity->delete();`

Nothing in `setCloneNull` has an effect to a deleted activity anyway

Also `setCloneNull($id, Activity $activity)`?

You are passing an id and the activity object? That doesn't seem good. And you can use `find($id)` instead of `where('id', '=', $id)`

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. The problem is that I have two activities. The original and the cloned. When I clone, the original gets "1" in 'hasClone' column. But when I delete the clone, I want the 'hasClone' column of the original to be 'NULL' again. But I can not save () in my destroy method because the route method is in DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Larvavels dependency injection. Just TypeHint the Model in the parameter list and Laravel takes care to get you the correct one by its ID.

Get the parent Activity from the database, set `hasClone` to `NULL`, store it and delete the activity.

```
public function destroyChanges(Activity $activity)
{
    $parentActivity = Activity::findOrFail($activity->parent_id);
    $parentActivity->hasClone = NULL;
    $parentActivity->save();

    $activity->delete();

    return redirect(url('/admin/activity/'));
}
```

Remove the post route of `Route::post('activity/setCloneNull/{id}'`.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is you’ve added a **POST** route for `setCloneNull()`, but a redirect will perform a **GET** request.